# R_function Predict()_using a test sample_Error object 'Pred' not found

Tags: r, arguments, eval, predict, nnet

I implemented a neural network algorithm with a training sample. Now I want to calculate the prediction of the model on a test sample.

My R code is the following:

```
rn=nnet(resignation~., data=T5_training[,-1], entropy=TRUE, 
        size=5, decay=2, MaxNWts=3000, maxit=2000)

T5_test$Pred = predict(rn,T5_test[,-1],type="class")
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Pred' not found

What is the origin of this error ?
I want to create the variable "Pred" (prediction of resignation on test sample), so I don't understand why R is looking for this variable... 
Above all there is no error when I use the fonction predict on the training sample : T5_training$Pred = predict(rn,T5_training[,-1],type="class")

(nb. Resignation is a binomial variable)

Thanks